# How to put and execute code into Keyword with JSR223?

Tags: jmeter, jsr223, console-output

I try to implement this : https://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-how-to-create-a-data-keyword-driven-framework-for-performance-testing/

I have a `.csv` file with the test case name in the first column. So I want to run a specfic test case according to the value in the `.csv`.

```
Test Plan
|--- Test Fragment
    |--- Switch Controller
         |--- Transaction Controller (TestCase1)
              |--- JSR223 Sample (TestCase1 script)   
         |--- Transaction Controller (TestCase2)
              |--- JSR223 Sample (TestCase2 script)   
         |--- Transaction Controller (TestCase3)
              |--- JSR223 Sample (TestCase3 script)
|--- Thread Group
     |--- CSV Data Set Config
     |--- Debug Sampler
     |--- ForEach Controller
          |--- Module Controller
     |--- View Result Tree
```

However if I put some code in `JSR223` into `Transaction Controller`, like `log.info("TEST !")` nothing is display into the console.

Is there a solution to execute code write into `JSR223` and display it into the console?

Moreover, in the `View Result Tree` I found this information: `testcasename=TestCase1`. So it seems to work but no log...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Simpy use [OUT](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead of `log`:

```
OUT.println("Hello Console");
```

> OUT - System.out - e.g. OUT.println("message")

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But even if I use `OUT.println("TEST")` nothing is display into the log. Maybe because the sampler is not in a `Thread Group` ?

Comment: @Royce `OUT` will display only in console, if you want also in log check @DmitriT answer

Comment: @Royce if you want to just log keyword with JSR223, you can use ${__logn("write here your log")} see https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__logn

Answer (score 0):

Given you use `log` shorthand you will be able to see your `TEST !` message only in [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

[image]

If you want to see the message in [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) you should use `println` instead like:

```
println("TEST !")
```

If you want to continue using `log` shorthand and to see the messages both in *jmeter.log* file and STDOUT - you will need to [amend JMeter logging configuration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) like:

- in *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
- Under `<Appenders>` tag add the following block:

  ```
  <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout>
          <pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
  </Console>
  ```
- Under `<Root>` tag add the following line:

  ```
  <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
  ```

[image]

Once you restart JMeter you should start seeing the same information as in the *jmeter.log* file in the STDOUT including your custom messages

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately even with your modifications, nothing is display. Please confirm to me that I can use JSR223 Sampler outside of a `Thread Group` ?

Comment: If nothing is displayed then the Sampler is not executed. You cannot use it outside of the Thread Group

Comment: So, if I follow this tutorial https://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-how-to-create-a-data-keyword-driven-framework-for-performance-testing/ how I'm supposed to write some code to define the keyword without a JSR223? thank you for your help.